# Find link from closest li and open it in a new page - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I have a submenu divided in two parts:in the right side a li which contains a link and in the left side an icon for each li.

Icons use a css class,called 'submenubtn'.I want to make a javascript function which takes the link from the closest li,assign to that icon,and when that icon is clicked,the link should be open in a new tab.

I hope I was clear enough,please ask me anything you didnt'n undertand.

here is the code i have until now:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("click", ".submenubtn", function() {
    var link = $(this).find("li").attr('href'); 
    //window.alert(link);
    window.open(link)
 });
 });
```

link returns "undifined".

I don't know how much this will help,but the html page:

```
<?Menu?>
<div id="<?$_name?>" class="atk-menu atk-menu-vertical atk-popover">
<ul>
    <?Item?>
        <?MenuItem?>
        <li id="<?$id?>" class="<?$class?>"> <a href="<?$href?>"><i class="<?$icon?>"></i><?label?>MenuItem<?/?></a></li>
        <?/MenuItem?>
    <?/?>
    <?$Content?>
</ul>
</div>
<?MenuSeparator?><?/MenuSeparator?>
<?/?>
```

**EDIT** I solved the problem..see in my answer the solution

Comment: how can add `href` attribute in `li` tag

Comment: i have to use this js function in a app that use a framework...its use should be generally in the application...not for a html file

Comment: Impossible to help without your HTML

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.location.href = link;`
and closest() function of JQuery to get what you want

To open it on a new window add  `window.open(link, '_blank')`

Comment: this is pretty close!except that it  opened another link,not the closest link(at least the link i want)...i changed to  `link=window.location.href` and replaced `find("li")` with `closest(li)`

Answer (score 1):

i think using data tags is the solution

here the soure: http://api.jquery.com/data/

new li html:

```
<li data-url="HERE THE URL!"/>
```

your new jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on("click", ".submenubtn", function() {
    var link = $(this).closest('li').data('url'); 
    //window.alert(link);
    window.open(link)
 });
 });
```

Comment: the link from li should not be hardcoded in html.it comes from db.but the code is good.

Comment: @AdiCrainic it is an example becouse i couldn know how your html is rendered. But a data tag is a good way to add additional data to a tag.

Answer (score 1):

`li` element cannot contain `href` attribute, you can give your li a `data` attribute such as:

```
<li data-href="your url here"></li>
```

then you can use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on("click", ".submenubtn", function () {
        var link = $(this).closest('li').data('url');
        window.open(link, '_blank');
    });
});
```

`find()` used to find the descendants of your element which is not applicable in your case since your anchor is the child of your `li` element.

So you need to use `closest()` to traverse up the DOM tree and get the closest parent `li` instead.

---

Try to use:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("body").on("click", ".submenubtn", function () {
        var link = $(this).closest('li').find('a').attr('url');
        window.location.href(link);
    });
});
```

Comment: the link comes from database.it can't be hardcoded in html.so i can't use that data('url').
but windows.location.href works.but it don't open the link from closest li.how should manage this without data('url')?

Comment: What is the HTML of your `li` look like?

Comment: it's a framework...i don't have access to the html in this project..so i think it can't be done?

Comment: You can use firebug or chrome developer tools to inspect your element? You can view the source of your site as well.

Comment: Where's your `.submenubtn` element?

Comment: my submenubtn is in `li`...`li` contains a text and that icon which use submenubtn class.only the icon has this class

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved**

I managed to solve this...it was pretty simple.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".submenubtn").click(function() {
        a =   $(this).closest('a').attr('href');
        window.open(a);
        return false;
 });
 });
```